# I am trying to add a few different GET variables to the url

Tags: php, pagination, get

I'm currently working on php pagination and I manage to get the code working... my problem now is that each time I click on the NEXT or PREVIOUS button the variable in the url will be no more..

please how do I make the variables already in the url stay fixed why the new pagination variables are added to the url...

My url

www.example.com/profile.php?id=2

When a click on the pagination previous or next button my url will look like

www.example.com/profile.php?pageno=4

My problem is how do I make the id=2 not leave even as I continue to click on the pagination button

www.example.com/profile.php?id=2&pageno=3

www.example.com/profile.php?id=2&pageno=4

www.example.com/profile.php?id=2&pageno=5

Pagination code.... please help me

```
    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    }
    $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","skyworld1_sky","uromiUROMI914@#","skyworld1_sky");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phonegap2";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM phonegap2 LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
    $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
echo "<tr><th>email</th>";
 echo "<th>fullname</th>";
  echo "<th>country</th>";
 echo "<th></th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
        //here goes the data


  echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['email'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['fullname'];

    echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['country'];

    echo "</td><td>";


    echo " <input type='submit' value='BUY'>";

    echo "</td><tr>";     







    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<ul align="center" class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

You need the ID field to show in the URL when a user clicks the previous or next links.

**Solution**

If you have an ID as a GET param you can simply pull it out of the URL and add it to your links in the page.

```
<a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?id=".$_GET['id']."&pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
```

**Example**

In my URL on page load I have -

> http://localhost?id=2

Then in the PHP page -

```
<?php
$total_pages = 100;
$pageno = 3;
?>

<a href="<?php echo "?id=".$_GET['id']."&pageno=".($pageno + 1); ?>">Next</a>
```

[image]